# iTextSharp C# text extration by table row

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have been extracting text from PDF which is having table and the text in the cell is not aligned unqiuely (Some cell is center aligned and some top, some having multiple lines in it).

Here, if I am trying to extract text by `LocationTextExtractionStrategy()`, this gives me text line by line and for obvious reason it miss text from some cells due to different alignment.

I tried to extend this LocationTextExtrationStrategy but I have very few understanding of the library.

Here, I am looking for a solution where either the gap between cells can be preserved while converting line by line or any way I can detect border of the row (line/ graphic) so that I may extract entire row instead of line.

FYI, below line of code is extracting text from PDF:

```
text = PDFTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
```

Comment: @KJ By center I meant vertically centered.

Comment: @KJ I am fine with white spaces if you have any workaround

Comment: @KJ page vertical center is not worth to me. We can try the sapces thing

Comment: @KJ okay, so what would you suggest?